# Uncaught reference error - function is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, parameters, parameter-passing

```
function generatePieChart(chartData, counter='', diffSeparator=''){     
  var chart;
  var legend;

//chartData = "["+chartData+"]";                        

AmCharts.ready(function () {
    // PIE CHART
    chart = new AmCharts.AmPieChart();
    chart.dataProvider = chartData;
    chart.titleField = "stage";
    chart.valueField = "enquiryCount";
    chart.depth3D = 10;
    chart.angle = 10;

    // LEGEND
    legend = new AmCharts.AmLegend();
    legend.align = "center";
    legend.markerType = "circle";
    chart.balloonText = "[[title]]<br><span style='font-size:14px'><b>[[value]]</b> ([[percents]]%)</span>";
    //chart.addLegend(legend);


    // WRITE
    chart.write("chart_div_"+diffSeparator+"_"+counter);
});


}

generatePieChart(<?=$data?>,'<?=$i?>','o');
```

I am trying to generate graphs as it needs to be generated 10 times. So, instead of placing the complete jquery, i created the generation section to a function as you can see. Then while calling the function, it is providing me error saying "Uncaught reference error".
I also checked many of the post's describing different solution. I tried all of them but none of them worked.
And the most annoying thing is that, the same script works in firefox but not in chrome.

Comment: on a sidenote: what does this have to do with PHP exactly? Please don't tag questions with tags that don't have anything to do with it.

Comment: @Tularis I agree, I guess the OP added this because the parameters to the function were PHP variables. I've removed this tag as it is misleading.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following line is not valid JavaScript

```
function generatePieChart(chartData, counter='', diffSeparator='') {
```

Remove the `=''` from the parameters.

The parameters will default to the datatypes of the values passed in to the function when it is called. Which in your example are strings anyway.